How can I let PSSE find my user defined model?
I writed a user defined model of machine's exciter and have created a dll of it. I  loaded the dll into model library but I can't find my model in model selection of machine's exciter in dyr.I also try to use API but the psse show my model name is not defined. Why and How can I let PSSE find it?
